# generating a create statement from a pre built graph in the neo4j browser

Tags: python, graph, neo4j

Essentially I have a script that generates a neo4j graph but it is only doing it in a local neoj browser. But I want to share these graphs with someone who doesn't have neo4j installed and I stumbled upon the neo4j console https://console.neo4j.org/ which would allow me to generate a link for someone to view the graph without the neo4j browser installed. The only issue is that I would need the whole cipher create statement to create it in this. My script uses the py2neo library to create the graphs, not cipher. So basically I need a way of taking a graph in the neo4j browser and generating a create a statement that would create that graph. Is this possible?

Comment: You can download the nodes/relationships into csv then create cypher statements to upload the data. OR you can use neo4j aura. It is free and neo4j cloud solution. I am not an endorser of neo4j aura :D

Comment: @jose_bacoy with neo4j aura would it be possible for me to share graphs with people who don't have a neo4j account, with just a link? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

With auradb(free) you can have a cloud hosted database.

If you want to expose the graph to other people.

I would probably not recommend giving them direct access but using a graph visualization library to render the graph for them in an webapp.

see: https://medium.com/neo4j/tagged/data-visualization for some examples.